# alter a jQuery script to auto rotate

Tags: jquery, banner, autorotate

Firstly I think this is a plugin so I hope I am posting in the right forum. I am building a site for a friend. I do not know how to use jQuery but have been able to find a dreamweaver template that has a carousel in it, I have added the images and am able to do all the html changes but I am really out of my depth when it comes to jQuery.

There are three files that relate to the script for the carousel and I am not sure where I even start to look for the correct code to edit, let alone what to edit it with. I have been watching tutorials on youtube and reading lots of information online about jQuery scripts but I think I know less now that when I started if thats possible.

So here is my first question, how do I change the carousel from one that I need to click to one that auto rotates and keeps the animation as I think it looks cool and question 2 after this project is completed I would really like to understand jQuery so where should I start and specifically what should I start with?

There is an unfinished version of the page online here 
        http://www.funfitbrighton.co.uk/index22.html and the scripts are here:

```
    /scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js
    /scripts/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js
    /scripts/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.setup.js
```

My understanding is really limited and so I have been looking in jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js file as I think this is where the new script should go, I have found some functions online however, where to put them and what to replace is just far too confusing. Here is that script and if someone can help I would be very grateful.

I have been looking at the code and to help my own understanding I wondered if this bit of code:

```
    function setupStarterRotation() { // Get the center item and collections of the items that
    will be // to the left and to the right var $centerItem = 
    data.itemsContainer.children('img').eq(options.startingItem - 1); var $previousItems = 
    $centerItem.prevAll(); var $nextItems = $centerItem.nextAll()
```

Would be the correct piece of code to edit, if so would this be the correct sort of function to add?

```
    function rotategal(param){ $('#slides').scrollTo(param.next().attr('href'), 500);              
    setTimeout(function() { rotategal(param); }, 500); } 
    rotategal($('a.nextpic'));
```

Thanks in advance and please let me know if this is the wrong place to ask this question. Matt

Comment: you can use the autoPlay option [http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel/options](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel/options)

Comment: Thank you very much Abraham, I see that I can set the speed and I can set it to auto play however, I have no idea where and how to implement this. Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to add the options in jquery.waterwheelCarousel.setup.js

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors if i try to edit what I think is the options, the var section at the top of the

Comment: this bit var data = {
                itemsContainer:         $(this),
                totalItems:             $(this).children().length,
                containerWidth:         $(this).width(),
                containerHeight:        $(this).height(),

Comment: I realise what I have done, I was in the wrong file, but I don't see any form of options to edit in the file you mention.

Comment: OK I'm really confused now, I think I have edited the options correctly, uploaded the files and still nothing, here is what I have added startingItem: 6,
   autoPlay: 200,
   pauseOnHover: true,
   carouselSpeed: 4000

Comment: actually that should read startingItem: 6, autoPlay: 2000, carouselSpeed 4000, pauseOnHover: true still doesn't seem to have affected the carousel though, do I need to edit any other files to make it work? Sorry for all the questions I really am in the dark here and your help is appreciated.